# Ionic capacitor hybrid mobile application

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, webview, capacitor, hybrid

I want to create a hybrid mobile app using ionic capacitor. When user logs in the app should open the main angular app in a hidden webview to initialize the angular app. The webview should be hidden for this time. After this when a user clicks on any links in mobile app, it should open in the webview and this time the webview should be displayed. The webview should open in the app container and not in the browser window (like InApp browser). Please help me if anybody have explored this kind of solutions.
My existing app is built using Xamarin and its built on the above concept.

I have tried the InApp browser but it does not give a good impression to the end user expecting a complete mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is more or less possible if I've understood you well. I've done it in my job. We have a ionic app, but then there are some native screens developed natively for Android (with Java) and iOS (with Swift). With ionic you can call native code from Javascript. For that you need to make your own local Capacitor plugin: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins

In a plugin, the ionic Javascript function will trigger a native function (Java/Kotlin for Android - Swift/ObjectiveC for iOS). Once there, you can freely create native screens (Android = Activity, iOS = Storyboard/Controller) and then launch your native screens in the app. In our project most of the app is ionic, but we developed our own native screens such as a PDF Viewer, a Web browser, a QR scanner, etc.

But an app is not like a website, an app is a **stack of screens**. Which means that everytime you access a new screen, it's added to the top of the stack and the user can go back to the previous one. So, ionic will launch first. Inmediately after starting the app (or whenever you want) you can move the user to a native (android/ios) screen. However, if the user presses the native android back button, he will come back to ionic. If you want to prevent that, you need to code that behavior yourself (google android prevent back button). Likewise, you "can't" make the user go from the  native screen to ionic, you can **bring him back** to ionic by navigating back programmatically.

Perhaps you can also change the launch activity to use a different one, and then later launch the ionic activity with native code. But I haven't done this myself and it could break ionic, so I can't advice you through this path.

I hope my answer helps, but I'm not sure I understood what you want to accomplish.